# Typescript Error:TS2345: Argument of type '{ theme: string; jsonFile: string; output: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumberjs

I am getting the error in the title from the following code:

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
import { mkdirp } from 'mkdirp'
import * as report from 'cucumber-html-reporter'
const Cucumber = require('cucumber')

export class CucumberReportExtension {

    private static jsonDir = __dirname + '/../../test/reports/json';
    private static htmlDir = __dirname + '/../../test/reports/html';
    private static jsonFile = CucumberReportExtension.jsonDir + '/cucumber_report.json';

    private static cucumberReporterOptions = {
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        jsonFile: CucumberReportExtension.jsonFile,
        output: CucumberReportExtension.htmlDir + '/cucumber_reporter.html',
        reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
        launchReport: true,
        metadata: {
            'App Version':'1.0.0',
            'Test Environment': 'Development',
            Browser: 'Chrome  84.0.4147.105',
            Platform: 'Windows 10',
            Parallel: 'Scenarios',
            Executed: 'Local'
        }
    }

    public static CreateReportFile(dirName) {
        // Check of the directory exist
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirName))
            mkdirp.sync(dirName);
    }

    public static GenerateCucumberReport(){

        report.generate(CucumberReportExtension.cucumberReporterOptions);
    }

}
```

My package.json contains:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.14",
    "faker": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "log4js": "^6.3.0",
    "log4js-protractor-appender": "^1.1.2",
    "mkdirp": "latest",
    "moment": "^2.28.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "stringinject": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.11",
    "@types/cucumber": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/load-json-file": "^5.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-smoothie": "^0.3.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.2.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "k6": "0.0.0",
    "load-json-file": "^6.2.0",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^1.16.3",
    "nodejs-nodemailer-outlook": "^1.2.3",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.2.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-etc": "^1.13.6",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the [expected type](https://github.com/gkushang/cucumber-html-reporter/blob/develop/index.d.ts) for the `Options` object passed to `report.generate`, I can see that the type which they expect for `theme` is a union of string literals.

Your theme `'bootstrap'` is one of those options, but in the error message you can see that typescript interpreted it as `string` instead of the literal string `'bootstrap'`.
You can use `as const` so that typescript sees it as a literal:

```
private static cucumberReporterOptions = {
     theme: 'bootstrap' as const,
     ....
```